# Serialize multiline string with |?

Tags: yamldotnet

Using YamlDotNet, the following string;

```
"blah blah blah \n blah blah blah"
```

gets serialized as:

```
test: >-
  blah blah blah

  blah blah blah
```

Is it possible to have this serialized as

```
test: |
  blah blah blah
  blah blah blah
```

dotnet fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/zT1Ujs

Answer (score 4):

Found it by searching github, add a `[YamlMember(ScalarStyle = ScalarStyle.Literal)]` attribute to the property works.